# Joomla SEF Apache mod_rewrite not working on new hosting setup, possible RewriteBase rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, migration, joomla-sef-urls

I recently moved my sub-domain hosted Joomla (sub.domain.com) to another host and my SEF URL's are broken. Currently I have Apache mod_rewrite turned off in the Joomla admin forcing the /index.php/ within all URL's

Apache mod_rewrite is loaded and working correctly. The major different in my hosting setup is that before my VPS host had a directory for the sub-domain within the server structure /home/me/sub.domain.com/ now it seems the new host is using another rewrite? as the server files is located in /var/www/domain.com whereas the front-end browser points to http://sub.domain.com

Not sure if there is a custom RewriteBase rule I'm not familiar with to correct this or perhaps there is another rewrite going on within the hosting which I'm not aware of?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Your not giving us a lot of info here. What are the paths of the document_root's of the main domain and the subdomain? What does the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable say for the main domain and the subdomain? My instinct says you should try playing with `RewriteBase`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure, that you DO NOT have set AllowOverride in your vhosts file to "none" ?